# the correct project properties compile target?

Tags: android, adt, google-gdk

This has been consistent across a lot of the glass code i've worked on. Why does the target API prefer the former instead of the latter?

Most of the projects I load into eclipse, I have to change the make target for my code to compile. This is the same for Google APIs:15 and GDK15

```
#target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:19
target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19
```

using android development tools eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an Android project, the Android Development Tools (ADT, based on Eclispse) default to the latest Android API level. Google Glass (and the sneak preview) are special conditions for Android (much like "Wear" is too).

To create a project that runs on Google Glass you need to use the "preview" Glass Development Kit as the target ... because there are hardware differences and a small set of features that are specific to Glass and require that implementation.

When you create an Android project, you have to create the appropriate target environment when you establish the project. For Google Glass, the original release required API level 15 (and the appropriate preview version). With XE16, the level became API level 19 (for compilation), and the newly released Glass Development Kit Preview that was moved up to support the latest Android API level.

Comment: ah ok, that was my understanding but most projects i stumbled on us #target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:19 instead of the preview kit. The GDK is Google API + the GDK, why do people target only Google API19?

Comment: For Google Glass you MUST use the preview.  For other Android projects, NOT meant to run on Google Glass, that "normal" Googla API is fine.